# Merging Meshes Ctrl+J but everything looks off (normals, uv?)

Tags: mesh, uv, normals

[image: pic]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnhql.jpg

tried renaming/flipping UV, recalculating normals, didnt seem to do much, any idea why?
[image]

Comment: have you tried reunwrapping the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the metallic object, rename its UV Map (in my example UV_B_Set_0).

Join with Ctrl J.

In the metallic material add a new Input > UV Map node, select the renamed UV Map and connect it on every vector input of every texture.

[image]

Comment: amazing, thanks alot! I guess i missed out some steps when using the uv map node